# Constrain width of NSTextField in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, width, constraints, nstextfield

I would like to use interface builder to display text in an NSTextField, which I can do.  But when the text is too long to fit normally in the space provided in the interface builder layout, I need to be able to constrain in.  I see the width constraint on the NSTextField, but it dent' behave exactly as I need.  I need to display the entire string, but to squeeze the font horizontally such that it compresses the string into the available space.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can change the font size in IB, until it fits, but unless it's only a little too long, the font will be ridiculously small.

Comment: What I need do do is adjust only the width, leaving the height alone.  For this, I don't think adjusting the font size will help.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: No, I don't know any way to do that, but even if you could, you would run into the problem of the text being so distorted that it would be hard to read.

Comment: The standard way of handling the case that you have mentioned above is to truncate the string.